# IOS - reset search bar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, searchbar

I'm working with UISearchBar. At the very start, the search bar looks like this:
[At the very start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goDf6.jpg)
And when we begin to edit, it looks like this:
[begin to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaLGJ.jpg)
And my question is how to reset the search bar(return to the very start status)?

Comment: By "very start status" you mean to remove the text or dismiss the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `IBOutlet` variable to your `UISearchBar`, just use :

```
searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
```

More infos about responder available on [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder).